# Firebase auth() subfunctions not recognized

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use Firebase to allow users to create accounts and sign in to a chat app. I've copy-pasted the code on Firebase's console to add a web app and have followed the docs for creating a user account with email and password. THe docs say to pass `email` and `password` to their function `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`, and although I've done the integration properly thus far, my IDE says that `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` is an unresolved method. I am working in a separate JS file called `main.js`, with the required JS files from Firebase in `<script>` tags above the tag that links `main.js` to `index.html`.

```
function submitAcc() {
                var email = document.getElementById("emailinput").value;
                var password = document.getElementById("passinput").value;
                firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error.log);
                    console.log(error.message);
                });
            }
```

is the problematic function in main.js and here

```
        <script>
            // Initialize Firebase
            var config = {
                apiKey: "censored",
                authDomain: "censored",
                databaseURL: "censored",
                projectId: "censored",
                storageBucket: "censored",
                messagingSenderId: "censored"
            };
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
        </script>
        <!-- Firebase App is always required and must be first -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.5/firebase-app.js"></script>

        <!-- Add additional services that you want to use -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.5/firebase.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.5/firebase-auth.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.5/firebase-database.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.5/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.5/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.5/firebase-functions.js"></script>

        <!-- Comment out (or don't include) services that you don't want to use -->
        <!-- <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.5/firebase-storage.js"></script> -->


        <!-- <script src="main.js" rel="script"></script> -->
        <script src="main.js"></script>
```

are the Firebase script tags copy-pasted from what the docs tell me to do. It's only `firebase.auth()` that doesn't work; we tried `firebase.database().ref()` to test and that works fine.

Comment: Did you try put your firebase initializer before `main.js` and above others Firebase script? I mean between those two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, there WAS no error, instead it was simply the IDE that had a problem. Upon testing the function performed as intended. For anyone else that has this error, try making an account as you would if you were a user and then checking the users under firebase > auth. This error occurred with the JetBrains WebStorm IDE.